# Attempted to update BIOS on my Toshiba Satellite, now it doesn't boot to Windows anymore

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, toshiba-laptop

I am using Toshiba Satellite u500-10l PSU5EE-002003AR, I download BIOS update from toshiba site, and trying to update when click the application file automatically shutdown the system. Now it doesn't open, I have tried safe mode but it does not boot Windows.

Comment: OK. I tried this.blue screen shows the problem."A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.

Comment: If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen,restart your computer. If this screen appears again ,follow these steps: Check for vireses on your computer.Remove any newly installed hard drives or hard drive controllers .Check your hard drive to make sure it is properly configured and terminated . Run CHKDSK /F to check for hard drive corruptrion ,and then restart your computer.

Comment: Technical information: ***STOP: OxOOOOOO7B (OxFFFFF88OOO9A98E8,OxFFFFFFFFCOOOOO34,.....)

Comment: Please help me ..now What I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If It's showing boot options, then before booting press <kbd>F8</kbd> and select from `advanced boot options` and <kbd>enter</kbd> `Disable automatic restart on system failure`
and select `Start Windows Normally`, then post here bluescreen error code.

[image]

Comment: @tom wijsman pls help me..

Comment: @tom ,how to attach the blue screen message,I typed here as comment.

Comment: no need, that code suffice. Restart computer and press F2 or Del, to access BIOS. In bios, look for `SATA Mode`, if you find that, post here what value is there and set it to another. (there are only 2, ahci or ide).

Comment: I Checked, "AHCI "shows.

Comment: Set it to `ide mode` save bios settings `F10` and reboot.